# Send multiple selected checkboxes values(record ids) to web api controller from angular side

Tags: angular, api, codeigniter

Is there a way to send selected checkboxes values as a comma separated string to web api controller if CodeIgniter(PHP framework)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

yes, only filter the array, map it and join it

if I imagine your data array is in the way, e.g.

```
[{id:1,checked:false,name:'igor},{id:2,checked:true,name:'aitor'}...]
```

You can do

```
const datasend=this.data.filter(x=>x.checked)  //filter and get only the "checked is true"
             .map(x=>x.id)  //get only the "id"
             .join(',')     //use join to create an string
```